# reading a .csv file into an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, database, sorting, csv

I have a class called EmpQuery that I am trying to create an array of objects for my Employee class to hold data that comes from a employeedatabase.csv file.
The database appears like what is shown below. I need to use a stream-processing-algorithm..

```
Loop till EOF{
read in 1 record
Deal with that record completly
}
```

EX.

```
Employee ID,Full Name,Department,Start Date,Earnings
EMP001,Adele M. Fulton,Engineering,10/28/2008,"$104,000.00"
EMP002,Ali T. Herman,Engineering,2/27/2012,"$337,522.00"
EMP003,Alika C. Crawford,Engineering,6/2/2009,"$144,000.00"
```

So far i just have this much set up
public class EmployeeDB {

```
    private static String[] empID = new String[300];
    private static String[] empName = new String[300];
    private static String[] department = new String[300];
    private static String[] startDate = new String[300];
    private static String [] earnings = new String[300];
    private static String [] empDataBase = new String[300];
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        fillDataArray();
    }

   public class employee{
      String empID;
      String empName;
      String department;
      String startDate;
      int earnings;

   public employee(String ID,String Name,String dept,String sDate,int earn){

          empName = Name;
          empID = ID;
          department = dept;
          startDate = sDate;
          earnings = earn;
   }      
    public employee( String ID, String Name)  {

          empName = Name;
          empID = ID;
          department = "";
          startDate = "";
          earnings = 0;

   } 
    public employee(){

           empName = "";
           empID = "";
           department = "";
           startDate = "";
           earnings = 0;

    }

   }
    private static String[] fillDataArray() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File DatabaseFile = new File("EmpDB_lab7.csv");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(DatabaseFile);
        String InputLine;
        String [] empDBTemp = null;
        int i=0;

        while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
            InputLine = inputFile.nextLine();
            empDBTemp = InputLine.split("-");
            empID[i] = empDBTemp[1];
            empName[i] = empDBTemp[2];
            department[i] = empDBTemp[3];
            startDate[i] = empDBTemp[4];
            earnings[i] = empDBTemp[5];
        }



    return empDBTemp;

    }
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at employeedb.EmployeeDB.fillDataArray(EmployeeDB.java:76)
    at employeedb.EmployeeDB.main(EmployeeDB.java:28)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Your requirements are here but not your effort. Show what you've done so far to solve this problem.

Comment: I have updated to where i have gotten so far with the error added

Answer (score 1):

CSV parsing is harder than it appears, so you should use a pre-existing library, such as [Super CSV](https://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/examples_reading.html)

Your CSV column names should match your bean field names (or skip the header altogether), and earnings could be a String, else you'll want to use a CellProcessor to parse it.

Reading stuff into an array and stream processing are contradictory.

```
ICsvBeanReader csvReader = new CsvBeanReader(new FileReader("employeedatabase.csv"), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

String[] header = csvReader.getHeader(false);

EmployeeDB employeeDB;

while((employeeDB = csvReader.read(EmployeeDB.class, header)) != null) {
    System.out.println(employeeDB.getEmpName());
}

csvReader.close();
```

And

```
public class EmployeeDB {

    private String empID;
    private String empName;
    private String department;
    private String startDate;
    private String earnings;

    ...getters/setters...
}
```

I changed the header to:

```
EmpID,EmpName,Department,StartDate,Earnings
```

Comment: Another choice of CSV parsing/generating library is [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/). Has worked very well for me. Handles [standard CSV](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180), non-standard CSV, and tab-delimited formats as well.